# Meaning of "=~" operator in shell script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I came across a shell script where the code is

```
for line in $LIST_ARRAY;do
if [[ $LIST_ARRAY =~ $line ]]
then
echo "true"
....
...
.
```

What is the use of `=~` in this case?

Comment: The way you're using that for-loop, you should really name your loop variable `word` instead of `line`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

it's the Equal Tilde operator that allows the use of  regex in an if statement.

> An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same
>   precedence as == and !=. When it is used, the string to the right of
>   the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched
>   accordingly (as in regex(3)). The return value is 0 if the string
>   matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise. If the regular expression is
>   syntactically incorrect, the conditional expression's return value is
>   2. If the shell option nocasematch is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters. Any part of the
>   pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash