# Check if parameter is value X or value Y

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, parameters, equality

I want to check in my bash script, if a variable is equal to value 1 OR equal to value 2.

I don't want to use something like this, because the 'if true statements' are the same (some big echo texts), when the variable is equal to 1 or 2. I want to avoid data redundancy.

```
if [ $1 == 1 ] ; then echo number 1 ; else
if [ $1 == 2 ] ; then echo number 2 ; fi
```

More something like

```
if [ $1 == 1 OR 2 ] ; then echo number 1 or 2 ; fi
```

Comment: Aside: `==` isn't a valid comparison operator inside `[`. Bash allows it as an extension, but the [relevant standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) only specifies `=` for string comparison.

Comment: Arguably duplicative of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157435/bash-string-compare-to-multiple-correct-values, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259259/bash-if-statement-to-check-if-string-is-equal-to-one-of-several-string-literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are comparing integer values, use the `bash` arithmetic operator `(())`, as

```
(( $1 == 1 || $1 == 2 )) && echo "number 1 or 2"
```

For handling-strings using the `regex` operator in `bash`

```
test="dude"
if [[ "$test" =~ ^(dude|coolDude)$ ]]; then echo "Dude Anyway"; fi
# literally means match test against either of words separated by | as a whole
# and not allow for sub-string matches.
```

Comment: `-o` is explicitly marked obsolete in the current revision of the POSIX standard. Use `[ one ] || [ another ]`. And `==` is a nonportable extension; use `=` for string comparisons in `[ ]`.

Comment: (see the `[OB]` markings in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most easy to extend option is a `case` statement:

```
case $1 in
    [12])
        echo "number $1"
esac
```

The pattern `[12]` matches `1` or `2`. For larger ranges you could use `[1-5]`, or more complicated patterns like `[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]` to match any number from `1` to `99`.

When you have multiple cases, you should separate each one with a `;;`.