# How to identify if string is not in list, or, is there an equivalent to '!=~'?

Tags: bash, syntax

I know that the [`=~` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441521/bash-regex-operator) can be used to identify that [a string *is* in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157435/bash-string-compare-to-multiple-correct-values)...

```
if [[ "$var" =~ ^(str1|str2|str3)$ ]]
     then
          echo "$var is in the list"
     else
          echo "$var is not in the list"
fi
```

...but this syntax is not efficient if I am only interested in the `else`:

```
if [[ "$var" =~ ^(str1|str2|str3)$ ]]
     then
          echo "foo" >/dev/null        #bogus anything to avoid empty "then" clause
     else
          my_awesome_function_here
fi
```

I know that if I was just checking against a single string, the `!=` operator could be used...

```
if [[ "$var" != "str1" ]]; then
     my_awesome_function
fi
```

...but `!=~` is not a valid operator.

Is there an equivalent to `!=~`? Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: If you've declared an associative array, as in `declare -A items=( [str1]=1 [str2]=1 [str3]=1 )`, then `[[ ${items[$var]} ]]` or `! [[ ${items[$var]} ]]` is considerably easier to maintain. (You don't need to worry about part of a string in an associative array having meaning as a regex!)

Comment: Oh awesome! I was unaware of the `if ! [[ ... ]]` functionality. Thanks!

Comment: `!` isn't specific to `[[`; you can use it with *any* command. (And yes, `if` will work with any command; that's why `if grep ...` is valid syntax, same as `if ! grep ...`).

Comment: Thanks for the info! And I'm using bash 3, so unfortunately I don't believe I can utilize associative arrays... :(

Comment: ahh -- yup. Blame Apple for being unwilling to ship GPLv3-licensed code. :/

Comment: BTW, about the empty-clause thing, consider using `:` -- it's a synonym to `true` traditionally given that kind of noop placeholder usage, and it's faster to invoke it than to need to open `/dev/null` as stdout to run `echo` as shown in the current code.

Comment: Ah sweet, that's also really helpful. Many thanks!!